# How to know what TOP and LEFT To use according to rotate degrees?

Tags: javascript, html, math, rotation

Mates, I'm really bad with math how can I do the following:

I'm rotating a div with:

`document.getElementById('pig').style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('180 + 'deg' + ')';`

And moving it with keypress, but i need to move it diagonally according to my degrees.

- Considering 0 degrees I should move my div to right only
- Considering 180 degrees I should move my div to left only
- Considering 90 degrees I should move my div to top only
- Considering 270 degrees I should move my div to bottom only

What magic do I need to use to know how much I should put on

`document.getElementById('pig').style.top`

and how much I should put on

`document.getElementById('pig').style.left`

If it's not clear, please ask me!

Comment: the 'pig' image, is a spaceship, so when it's with its propulsion directed to bottom, my spaceship will move to top when someone press 'space' to accelerate it.

Comment: So "degrees" indicates the direction that the element should move? Did you mean 270 and not 120? Also, consider working on the [unit circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle), where `0°` would point right, `90°` points up, and `180°` points left.

Comment: You want to move the "pig" related to its own angle?

Comment: yes mate! the pig will be a spaceship.

Answer (score 0):

Convert degrees to [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian):

```
var deg = /* whatever */;
var rad = deg * (Math.PI/180);
```

and then use [`Math.sin()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin) and [`Math.cos()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos) to get the vertical and horizontal components, respectively:

```
 var yComponent = Math.sin(rad);
 var xComponent = Math.cos(rad);
```